# How to monitor the GCE? OS and App Level

Tags: performance, monitor

Is there any easy way to monitor my os metrics like CPU/ Memory /Disks, etc. and get alert is they reaches in some certain threshold? 
Also, I like to Monitor, my Java app running in tomcat/mongodb, I like to monitor the heap usage, threads, etc

Any recommendation?